# how to define the initial position of a specific column in linux or R

Tags: r, awk, sed, format

I have the following file, which is the result of merging Column 1 and Column 2

```
testing_MAS_180        00010111
testing_MAS_181        20100111
testing_MAS_182        20001101
cheeset_MAS_1    200000011211
cheeset_MAS_2    201001001121
cheeset_MAS_3    201012111121
Shejulio_MAS_9  2120002121
Shejulio_MAS_10 100101121
Shejulio_MAS_11 002101220
Shejulio_MAS_12 011011112
```

but the second column should start at the same position. My file should look like this

```
testing_MAS_180        00010111
testing_MAS_181        20100111
testing_MAS_182        20001101
cheeset_MAS_1          200000011211
cheeset_MAS_2          201001001121
cheeset_MAS_3          201012111121
Shejulio_MAS_9         2120002121
Shejulio_MAS_10        100101121
Shejulio_MAS_11        002101220
Shejulio_MAS_12        011011112
```

I tried these:

1. Before the merging, I tested if the first column had a tab or space at the end of the line with:
   cat vet df and sed 's/[[:blank:]]*$//' df
   But don't show space or tabs
2. I tried:

   - expand or unexpand for change space/tab
   - sed 's/ //g'
   - awk -v OFS="\t" '$1=$1' df > df1

but none of the commands worked

I tried too with a write.fwf R-command from ("library gdata)

```
write.fwf(x=geno_transformed, file=file, quote=TRUE); but the result was: Error in 

do.call(data.frame, c(x, alis)) : 
  variable names are limited to 10000 bytes
```

Any suggestions to solve this?

Comment: `column -t file`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
testing_MAS_180        00010111
testing_MAS_181        20100111
testing_MAS_182        20001101
cheeset_MAS_1    200000011211
cheeset_MAS_2    201001001121
cheeset_MAS_3    201012111121
Shejulio_MAS_9  2120002121
Shejulio_MAS_10 100101121
Shejulio_MAS_11 002101220
Shejulio_MAS_12 011011112
```

then

```
awk '{printf "%-23s%s\n",$1,$2}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
testing_MAS_180        00010111
testing_MAS_181        20100111
testing_MAS_182        20001101
cheeset_MAS_1          200000011211
cheeset_MAS_2          201001001121
cheeset_MAS_3          201012111121
Shejulio_MAS_9         2120002121
Shejulio_MAS_10        100101121
Shejulio_MAS_11        002101220
Shejulio_MAS_12        011011112
```

Explanation: I use [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html) with dash number s, which denotes left-justed text of width 23 and s which denotes just text. Feel free to adjust value (`23` in example) to your needs.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: We don't have to hardcode the width, we can extract it from the first line: `gawk 'NR == 1 {match($0, /(.+[[:blank:]])[^[:blank:]]/, a); width = length(a[1])} {printf "%-*s%s\n", width, $1, $2}'`

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's/\S+$//;s/././g;s#.*#:a;/^&$/!s/$/ /;ta#;q' file |
sed -Ee 'h;s/\S+$//' -f - -e 'x;s/^\S+\s*//;x;G;s/\n//' file
```

The solution is in two parts:

The first part writes the sed code to left align the first field of each line taking as its template the first line of the file of data.

The second part, splits each line into two fields and applies the code from the first part to left align first field, the second field is then appended to the first and the result printed.

The first part produces sed code like:

```
:a;/^.......................$/!s/$/ /;ta
```